# Asp.net linq query

Tags: c#, linq

```
System.Linq.IQueryable<CustomerProfile> query = 
    from usr in context.customer_profiles
    where usr.cust_email == LoginID
    select new CustomerProfile
    {
        NAME = usr.cust_name,
        CONTACT = usr.cust_contact,
        EMAILID = usr.cust_email,
        LOCATION = usr.cust_location,
        SERVICELOCATION=usr.cust_service_location,
        FAXNO=usr.cust_fax_no,
        FIRMNAME = usr.cust_firm_name,
        FIRMADDRESS = usr.cust_firm_address,
        DATEESTABLISHED = Convert.ToDateTime(((DateTime?)usr.date_of_established)),
        SIGNATURE = usr.cust_signature,
        LOGO =  usr.logo,
    };
```

At the following line, I get the issue of "specified cast is not valid". How can I correct this?

```
return query.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Can you tell the details of the exception, like inner exception or StackTrace?

Comment: What's the type of `usr.date_of_established`? Anyway, the explicit cast followed by a Convert is redundant. Further: you fetch _all_ `customer_profiles` from the database by this query. The ToList() is not necessary. I bet that the exception has to do with the datetime. Does it still occur if you omit that line?

Comment: Another question: what is the signature of the method that all this code is in. Does it expect to return something else?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a customers email to their login id in your query. I assume this would cause a casting issue, if not it probably wont return the correct results you want.

And use an implicit cast (var) rather than IQueryable

Comment: That would cause a compiler error like _Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'_.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and then return query. Sorry about the formatting, it was giving me the blues

```
        CustomerProfile query =
         (from usr in context.customer_profiles
          where usr.cust_email == LoginID
          select new
          {
              NAME = usr.cust_name,
              CONTACT = usr.cust_contact,
              EMAILID = usr.cust_email,
              LOCATION = usr.cust_location,
              SERVICELOCATION = usr.cust_service_location,
              FAXNO = usr.cust_fax_no,
              FIRMNAME = usr.cust_firm_name,
              FIRMADDRESS = usr.cust_firm_address,
              DATEESTABLISHED = Convert.ToDateTime(((DateTime?)usr.date_of_established)),
              SIGNATURE = usr.cust_signature,
              LOGO = usr.logo,
          }).FirstOrDefault();
```